# The transform property in CGPathAddEllipseInRect

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, quartz-graphics, cgpath

I am using `CGPathAddEllipseInRect` to draw a circle and then using that in CAKeyframeAnimation.  My issue is that the animation always starts in the same spot.  I thought that I could do the following with a CGAffineTransform to make it start in a different point:

```
CGAffineTransform temp = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(animationPath , &temp, rect);
```

I do not know what this is doing.  When it runs, I don't even see this portion of the animation.  It is doing something offscreen.  Any help understanding this would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rotation happens around the origin (0,0) by default, but you want to rotate around the center of the circle, so you have to do additional transformations:

```
float midX = CGRectGetMidX(rect);
float midY = CGRectGetMidY(rect);
CGAffineTransform t = 
    CGAffineTransformConcat(
        CGAffineTransformConcat(
            CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-midX, -midY), 
            CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)), 
        CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(midX, midY));
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(animationPath, &t, rect);
```

Essentially, this chains three transformations: First, the circle is moved to the origin (0,0), then the rotation is applied and afterwards it is moved back to its original position. I've made a little visualization to illustrate the effect:
[image]

I chose a square instead of a circle and 45° instead of 90° to make the rotation easier to see, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Great answer - but can you possibly explain it a little more.  When you say the origin, I would assume it is the origin of the rect that I am passing CGPathAddEllipseInRect.  But if that were the case, then I should still see it on screen, which isn't happening.  If it were the origin for the screen, then I assume I'd see it do a quarter of its rotation in the bottom corner of the screen which also isn't happening.  When I log the rect on one of the calls I am getting this - {{633.066, 600.916}, {40, 40}}.  The layers are being randomly place which is why the coords may seem funny.

Comment: I've added some additional explanations and a visualization to my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the diagrams.  They make it a lot easier to see what your code is doing.  The part I am still struggling with is what the code I had written is doing.  From what you've said, I assumed that when I run it, I would see a circle coming in and out of frame at the bottom-left corner of the screen.  But nothing ever happens.  I even placed another dot at 5,5 to make sure I have the correct corner for 0,0.  The width and height of my rect is 90.0 so I would assume it should come into frame.  Thanks again for the help.  Do you recommend any resources for better understanding this?

Comment: Imagine rotating the first image by 90° around the origin (0,0). Everything would be under the X-axis afterwards, so nothing would be within the view's coordinate system. You can use two pieces of paper to make it easier to visualize. I think it would be easier to see what's going on in your code, if you'd experiment with a smaller angle, like π/4 (45°).

Comment: Do you know of any documentation that I can look at to get a better understanding of this.  This isn't how I thought it would work from reading Apple's documentation.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I can recommend the book "Programming with Quartz" by David Gelphman and Bunny Laden. It predates the iPhone and Core Animation, but Quartz2D (which is what you're dealing with here) hasn't changed much since. Apple's Quartz 2D Programming Guide might also be helpful, esp. the chapter on tranforms: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-SW1